# Java Regular expression to restrict unwanted matchings

Tags: java, regex

I want a java regular expr to match `*T/N` , `*TA` , `*TI`, `*TA/O`, `*TI/O`, `*TA/N` and `*TI/N` but should not accept `*T`. The following regular expression pattern

```
String pattern="\\*T[AI]?(/N|/O)?";
```

is matching all the conditions but its matching `*T` also. How can I prevent it from matching `*T` as well?

Comment: Please reformat your question and give us sample inputs and expected outputs at least.

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, then you have a fixed set of valid inputs. Is it really necessary to check against a regex in this case? Maybe a set of constants to check against is easier, more maintainable and even performs better.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, it seems you can use a positive lookahead to make sure there are at least 2 allowed characters after `*T`:

```
String pattern = "\\*(?=[TAI/]{2})T[AI]?(?:/[NO])?";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP2lL7/1)

The `(?=[TAI/]{2})` positive lookahead will make sure there are 2 characters after `*`, either `T`, `A`, `I` or `/`.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor! This expresssion is restricting *T and accepting *T/N , *TA , *TI, *TA/O, *TI/O, *TA/N and *TI/N.